# How to implement ViewModels for asp.net MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to asp.net, there are some questions on stack overflow but they don't fulfill my purpose. My question is..

How would I implement view model for the following two models?

```
public class model1
{

int student-id{ get;set}

string student-name{get; set;}

}

public class model2
{

int course-code{get; set;}

string course-name{get; set;}

}
```

Now I want to write a view model that could pass to a view and this view displays student-name and corresponding course-names.

Note: a student can enrolled in more than one course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should modify your **model**. Student and courses have to be related. You can implement these relations like:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }

}

public class Course
{
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

After - you create view model. View model class must contain only what you actually need in you view. In you case - student and courses names. You can consider several options here. If you want just to display all course names in one line you can build you **StudentViewModel** like this:

```
public class StudentViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // In this case you can just join all courses' names to one string using string.Join(", ")
    public string Courses { get; set; }
}
```

... or like this - if you want courses' names separated (to use them in some select or list html element). But you can create `JoinedCources` property which will return courses' names joined into one string.

```
public class StudentViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<string> Courses { get; set; }
    public string JoinedCources { 
         get {
             return string.Join(", ", Courses);
         }
    }
}
```

**Note:** this is view model for only one student! If you want to display view which shows you the list of students and their courses you should either create new view model with property which is collection of `StudentViewModel` or in your view define model like `@model ICollection<StudentViewModel>` instead of `@model StudentViewModel`.

Now you have to map your model to view model. For example in your controller action when you get your student from database (or any other data source - file or web service):

```
public ActionResult StudentDetails(int studentId)
{
     var student = _dataSource.GetStudent(studentId);
     var model = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<StudentViewModel>(student);
     return View(model);     
}
```

Now few words about mapping. `AutoMapper` is external class library you should definitely get to learn about if you want to work with view models and mapping in the future. It will help you simplify action method code and make it more readable. But since you're new to ASP. Net you can implement mapping by your self for the first time. For example like below:

```
public ActionResult StudentDetails(int studentId)
{
     var student = _dataSource.GetStudent(studentId);
     var model = new StudentViewModel()
     {
         Name = student.Name,
         Courses = student.Courses.Select(c => c.Name)
     }
     return View(model);     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class StudentViewModel
{
   public string Name{get;set;}
   public int StudentId{ get;set}
   public List<model2> Courses
}
```

You can consider combining the two models into the above view model if the goal is to display a student with course info.